# getting lat long from adding multiple markers on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to find lat and long that I've added on maps. I've aldready tried so many things but can't figured out.

[here is my full code](http://jsfiddle.net/XWZ3v/)

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41,29),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });
}

function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
draggable: true
  });
  map.panTo(position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: just push em onto an array once u add them?
AFAIK google maps api doesn't support to get a reference to a marker which was added before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supernova is right - Google Maps API does not provide a way to reference markers once they have been added to the map in any other way than by keeping the original `google.maps.Marker`. A simple solution is to define an array outside of your function and to push all your markers on it one by one as they are created. A function for this could be similar to this:

```
(function() {
   var markers = [];
   window.addMarkerToMap(parameters, map) {
     var params = parameters || {};
     params.map = map;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker(params);
     markers.push({ "object": marker, "lat": params.position.lat(), "long": params.position.long() });
     return marker;
   };
   window.getMarkers() {
     return markers;
   };
})();
```

This gives you the `addMarkerToMap()` global function with signature: `parameters: Object, map: google.map`. Every time you add a marker using it, it will be available in the array returned by `window.getMarkers()`. From there, the marker is conveniently in `object`, while lat/long coordinates are in `lat` and `long` respectively.